# Development tools

Tags: c#, java

What programming language are windows applications begin built with these days? from what I can see when looking at job descriptions, Java and C# are mostly used for web applications.  I found a couple of companies looking for a c# winforms developer but the job also includes some web development as well. I think that is right since.net is web orientated.

Any comments please

Comment: .NET is more than just web development; it's a framework for building applications, some of which happen to be web-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally work with C#, Java use for Android development even if there is C# alternative. Mobile development is something which will grow more and more. It's very different, as is now, from desktop and web development and  I personally consider It most challenging from soft engineering perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about the most popular programming languages:

http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Ten-Programming-Languages-for-2011/

So, you we're right. Either learn Java or C#, and you are in business. 
C# is my personal favorite, because it's just as useful for winforms as for web!

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you how i've chosen a language and platform to work so you can take few ideas from there. I live in Israel, where Microsoft technologies are popular even though PHP was partly invented in Israel. More popular means more jobs.

I had deep knowledge in HTML/CSS from my background as designer so Web development on .NET framework aka ASP.NET was a natural choice for me.

I had previous knowledge in Action Script ( language that Flash/Flex applications are using ) and Javascript which is used on every website today, since these are C based language C# which is re-incarnation of C language was again a natural choice for me instead of VB.

You can develop Windows applications using .NET languages, Ruby, Python, Java, ActionScript via AIR and many more. Maybe i'm wrong on this but if you have no knowledge or what-so-ever on programming world you will better of starting with something less complex so native Windows framework can be a good choice ( i'm mean .NET)...

Any of those languages can be used for web applications as well, via frameworks ( dozens of already written functions and classes to ease on your programming experience )

just few thoughts...